# How can i do multiple joins between 2 tables in ODI?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I want to join 2 tables on 3 columns in ODI. When i do it during the mapping, in the target table, the 3 columns are empty.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to do 3 joins between the 2 tables and then a 4th join between the 3 joins but it doesn't work

Comment: So, no error, but your columns aren't populated? Can you post the strunctures and data of the two tables and then gives us the generated query from ODI?

Comment: Couldn't you use only 1 join component and put your 3 pair of columns matching in the same condition property? `a.column1= b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2 AND a.column3 = b.column3` ?